# Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, linux, file, ubuntu, server

```
public String moveFilestoDestinationFolder(String src_loc,String desc_loc) {

    String msg="";

    try {


        File srcfile =new File(src_loc);
        //change permission to 777 for all the users
        //no option for group and others
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 file"); 

        srcfile.setExecutable(true, false);
        srcfile.setReadable(true, false);
        srcfile.setWritable(true, true);

    //  srcfile.renameTo(new File(desc_loc));

        if(srcfile.renameTo(new File(desc_loc))){

            msg="File is moved successful!";
        }else{

            msg="File is failed to move!";
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStacktrace();
    }

    return msg;
}
```

This is the code that is used to move the file from one folder to another. But it's not working. Here I have set all file permissions. Still it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error? The output will probably always be "failed to move" because you try to move it twice.

Comment: I am not getting any message.Its not at all going to if loop @RealSkeptic

Comment: Please change the content of the `catch` from `e.getMessage()` (which does nothing because it only gets the message and doesn't print), to `e.printStackTrace()` which will print the error if there is an error. Run it again, and update your question with the information from the error.

Comment: **Update your question with the information from the error**. Do not write long information in comments.

Comment: @RealSkeptic-What is that error mean?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling`renameTo()` twice. If the first rename works, the second can't possibly work, and if the first doesn't work, the second one can't either.

Remove the first one.

Comment: i removed one but its showing some error as  Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(

Answer (score -1):

try to give permission of source file as

```
File srcfile =new File(src_loc);
    //change permission to 777 for all the users
    //no option for group and others
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 "+srcfile );
```

Plz try with this

Comment: Tried this but its showing error...java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)